# Derivative of multilinear function

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Theorem: Let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be differentiable vector-valued functions. Then the multilinear function $M(x_1, ... ,x_n)$ is differentiable.

[This is the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqAh4.png): I know that $M$ is linear in $x_1, \dots, x_n$, so that if for all $x_i$ (for $i \neq j$) the function M is linear, then it is a linear function of $x_j$.
But I can't understand the given proof.

Comment: Hint: use the definition of what it means for a multilinear function to be differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By expanding along a basis, it is straightforward to show that $M$ is continuous.

If a function has continuous partials then it is differentiable. It is not hard to see
that
$M(x_1,...,x_k+h,...x_n) - M(x_1,...,x_k,...x_n) - M(x_1,...,h,...x_n) = 0$ so it follows
that
${\partial M(x_1,...,x_n) \over \partial x_k}h = M(x_1,...,h,...x_n)$ and so is continuous. Hence $M$ is differentiable and

$DM((x_1,...,x_n))(h_1,...,h_n) = \sum_k {\partial M(x_1,...,x_n) \over \partial x_k}h_k$.

Comment: The notation is confusing to me. Since the $x_i$ are vector-valued functions, say $x_i$ lands in $\mathbb R^{n_i}$, we would have $M:\mathbb R^{n_1}\times\dots\times\mathbb R^{n_k}\to\mathbb R$, instead of $M:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$, which seems to be what your solution implies?

Comment: @ShaVuklia the question did not specify either the domain of $M$ or the range of the $x_k$ but it doesn't matter. I am not sure why you think my solution implies the last statement.

Comment: The expression $\sum_k \frac{\partial M(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{\partial x_k}h_k$ doesn't make sense to me, since we have $h_1,\dots, h_n$, while we have $n_1+\dots+n_k$ different partial derivatives.

Comment: @ShaVuklia I am not sure what to say, the derivative is a linear map $(h_1,...,h_n) \to $ whatever the range of $M$ is. There are $n$ partial derivatives with respect to the $x_k$.

Comment: I interpreted $\partial/\partial x_k$ as taking the directional derivative in the $e_k$ direction, but I see now that you mean it differently.